# Android NanoHttpd serve endless stream

Tags: java, android, webserver, streaming, nanohttpd

I`m trying to serve stream with latest (2.3.1) NanoHttpd. Here is code for the server:

```
public class Server extends NanoHTTPD {
PipedInputStream in;

public void setStream(final PipedInputStream in) {
    this.in = in;
}

public Server() throws IOException {
    super(null, 8888);
}
@Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    Response res = newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.OK, "audio/mpeg", in);
    res.setChunkedTransfer(true);
    return res;
}
```

Then I`m creating server instance like this:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                final PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out);


                audioTrack2 = new Server();
                audioTrack2.start();
                audioTrack2.setStream(in);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("server", "DOESNT START");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

where out:

```
 PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
```

Then, I have a callback. An In this callback I`m trying to write data to the outStream:

```
out.write(bytes);
```

So what I am waiting for: I open my browser on ip-adress:8888 and I can see audio play icon. But can not listen the stream I wrote to the pipe. I event didnt receive that stream because frist time I`m trying to open web-link I am getting this errors stack:

> 12:32:26.685 ss.serven.rduwan.airtunesandroid E/request #: 0
>   10-30 12:32:26.780 ss.serven.rduwan.airtunesandroid E/fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD: Could not send response to the client
>                                                                                  java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
>                                                                                      at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:542)
>                                                                                      at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:511)
>                                                                                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:500)
>                                                                                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.-wrap1(PlainSocketImpl.java)
>                                                                                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
>                                                                                      at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response$ChunkedOutputStream.write(NanoHTTPD.java:1442)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1694)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1667)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1654)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1624)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:957)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:192)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                                   Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
>                                                                                      at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:211)
>                                                                                      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278)
>                                                                                      at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:509)
>                                                                                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:500) 
>                                                                                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.-wrap1(PlainSocketImpl.java) 
>                                                                                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266) 
>                                                                                      at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82) 
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response$ChunkedOutputStream.write(NanoHTTPD.java:1442) 
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1694) 
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1667) 
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1654) 
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1624) 
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:957) 
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:192) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>   10-30 12:32:26.798 ss.serven.rduwan.airtunesandroid E/request #: 1
>   10-30 12:32:26.803 ss.serven.rduwan.airtunesandroid E/fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD: Could not send response to the client
>                                                                                  java.io.IOException: InputStream is closed
>                                                                                      at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:293)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1690)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1667)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1654)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1624)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:957)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:192)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   10-30 12:32:29.937 ss.serven.rduwan.airtunesandroid E/request #: 2
>   10-30 12:32:29.939 ss.serven.rduwan.airtunesandroid E/fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD: Could not send response to the client
>                                                                                  java.io.IOException: InputStream is closed
>                                                                                      at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:293)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1690)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1667)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1654)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1624)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:957)
>                                                                                      at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:192)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

In chrome`s dev console I can see I`d received 135b And then timeout out (with failed) after 5 seconds. Iam sure I`m sending a lot of bytes in out.write() so its deffenetly not only 136bytes. To be honest, as for now Iam never trying to close thats piped streams, so data should come to the browser endless. 
Here`s chrome screenshot:[image]
What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: "A pipe is said to be _broken_ if a thread that was providing data bytes to the connected piped output stream is no longer alive".

Comment: So why? If no client connected to the web pipe is writting OK.

Comment: because thread has stopped, presumably. I also don't understand what do you mean  by "if no client connected the pipe is OK". How do you know it's OK if noone's listening?

Comment: Becase Iam writting to it successfully. And after client is connected I can not write to pipe anymore. (IOException)

Comment: `Then I'm creating server instance like this:` Why are you doing that in the run() of a runnable of a thread? You dont need a thread as far as i know.

Comment: I`ve tried with/without separated Threads. Result is the same. Anything else?

Comment: `res.setChunkedTransfer(true);` Why are you setting that? Try to do without. Why would you use a chunked response at all?

Comment: Done. Its not a problem. Tried.